# I have a problem with the modules Bitnami Odoo 12 Google

Tags: google-cloud-platform, odoo, bitnami

I have a problem with the modules in Bitnami Odoo 12 for Google Cloud.
I am studying the fundamentals of Odoo, and I was able to create my first module, all right, I appeared in the list of modules and installed it, now I am in lesson 2 where I create basic models for this module, I did everything with care, even following the steps odoo documentation, but update, restart the server and the VM several times, but in the list of models does not appear what I created.

What is happening?

Comment: Did you go to your module (in the Odoo **Apps** menu) and "Upgrade" your module after restarting the Odoo server? If so, then you'll need to include the code being used in your module. My next guess would be that you aren't including your Python code via `import`.

Comment: Which Odoo version do you develop on? Have in mind that there was a big user change with Odoo 12. The admin account is not SuperUser anymore, so you need to create model rights for it. That wasn't necessary until Odoo 11. Without those rights, you won't see any menues of your new models. The official documentation and tutorial isn't updated for that big change, so skip to [Security](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/howtos/backend.html#security) to look how to create those access rights.

Comment: Thanks for your support, in the end just install from the Git source, I will never go back to Bitnami to develop.

Answer (score 0):

Odoo installed modules get's imported, as other's already mentioned in the comment. So if you don't `import` your models definition. For example, let's say your model definition `.py` files are organized as following:

```
root_addon_directory/
__init__.py

    models/
    __init__.py
    my_model.py
```

Then you can import your model definition using relative path import as following:

> root_addon_directory __init__.py file content

```
from . import models
```

> models directory __init__.py file content

```
from . import my_model
```

Comment: Hello, I made sure of that too, well at the end I gave up and I got rid of "bitnami" I guess it must be some special configuration they do, I uninstalled Bitnami and I installed Odoo 12 from Git and I can update the models. Thank you.